# ASP.NET MVC Routing why do I get error with localhost:8888/Index and not localhost:8888/

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In HomeController I have:

```
    public String Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome";

        return "hello";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are skipping your Controller name in your URL.

The default route is [ControllerName]/Index/[Optional ID Value]

So if you were to browse to http://localhost:8888/Home or http://localhost:8888/Home/Index you would see the expected results.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try http://localhost:8888/Home/Index. Otherwise it will treat Index as the controller part instead of the action part.